# Javafx2.2: Checkboxes in table view mess up when table is scrolled

Tags: checkbox, javafx, scroll, tableview

This issue happens when using the vertical scroll bar that comes with the table view. This is what my table view looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7Wv3.png

When you scroll with the mouse wheel, it's fine. When you scroll with the up/down arrows on the scroll bar, it's fine. But when you actually drag the scroll bar with your mouse pointer, then the selections in the checkboxes get messed up. For instance if you see the image linked above, the third checkbox is selected. After scrolling, the 5th checkbox might now be selected or the 2nd one. Or even two other checkoxes might be selected.

I believe this is a refresh/repaint problem with the table view's scroll bar.

The proper way to solve this would be to intercept the vertical scroll event and manually refresh the grid whenever the user scrolls. To do that I need to be able to get a handle on the table's scrollbar. Something like table.getScrollBar().setEventHandler(this). I am unable to do that. The table's scrollbar seems to be hidden. If I am unable to get to the scroll bar, I can't intercept the scroll event, and I can't fix this problem.

Here is what my fxml looks like:

```
<TableView fx:id="table" prefWidth="650" prefHeight="200" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0">
<columns>
    <TableColumn fx:id="nameCol" text="Product Type" prefWidth="125" />
    <TableColumn fx:id="totalCol" text="Total" prefWidth="65" />
    <TableColumn fx:id="entitledCol" text="Entitled"  />
    <TableColumn fx:id="forPurchaseCol" text="For Purchase" prefWidth="125" />
    <TableColumn fx:id="nonImmediate" text="Non Immediate" prefWidth="125" />
</columns>              
</TableView>
```

Here is the pertinent java code from the controller:

```
nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("productFullName"));
totalCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Integer>("totalCount"));
entitledCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Integer>("entitledImmediateCount"));
forPurchaseCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, ObservableMap<String, Number>>(
                                                                                                      "forPurchaseImmediateCountAndPrice"));
nonImmediate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Integer>("nonImmediateCount"));
forPurchaseCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Product, ObservableMap<String, Number>>, TableCell<Product, ObservableMap<String, Number>>>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell<Product, ObservableMap<String, Number>> call(TableColumn<Product, ObservableMap<String, Number>> col) {
        return new PriceCell();
    }
});
```

This is what PriceCell.java looks like:

```
public class PriceCell extends TableCell<Product, ObservableMap<String, Number>> {
private CheckBox box = new CheckBox();

@Override
protected void updateItem(ObservableMap<String, Number> countPrice, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(countPrice, empty);

    if(countPrice != null) {
        int count = (Integer) countPrice.get("count");
        if(count == 0) {
            setText("0");
        }
        else {
            setText(countPrice.get("count") + " ($" + countPrice.get("price") + ")");
            box.setOnAction(this);
            box.setId(countPrice.get("price").toString());
            setGraphic(box);
        }
    }
    else {
        setText("");
        setGraphic(null);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow your model is not well connected...

`PriceCell` is trying to mix in one single column two different contents: A boolean for the checkbox, which its state is not stored or processed when the cell is rendered, and which `has no field in`Product`, and a string, which is not related to the check state. So when the user clicks the check, the label won't be affected.

While the render seems correct, when you scroll with the mouse the checkbok state is lost, and there's no callback to find it properly.

There's already an implementation of a TableCell with a checkbox: `CheckBoxTableCell`. But it only takes `Boolean` as a parameter, since it only needs to know the status (selected or not). You could add some `StringConverter` for the label, but this is only related to the selected state.

To fix this problem, my suggestions are:

First, create a new field in `Product`:

```
private final BooleanProperty purchase = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

public boolean isPurchase() {
    return purchase.get();
}

public void setPurchase(boolean value) {
    purchase.set(value);
}

public BooleanProperty purchaseProperty() {
    return purchase;
}
```

And add a proper string formatter:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    if(isPurchase()){
        return forPurchaseImmediateCountAndPrice.get("count") + " ($" + forPurchaseImmediateCountAndPrice.get("price") + ")";
    }
    return "0";
}
```

In the controller:

```
forPurchaseCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>( "purchase"));
forPurchaseCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Product, Boolean>, TableCell<Product, Boolean>>() {

    @Override
    public TableCell<Product, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Product, Boolean> col) {
        return new PriceCell();
    }
});
```

And finally, modify `PriceCell`:

```
public class PriceCell extends TableCell<Product, Boolean> {
    private final CheckBox box = new CheckBox();

    public PriceCell(){
        box.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()).setPurchase(box.isSelected());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if(!empty){
            box.setSelected(item);
            setText(getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()).toString());
            setGraphic(box);
        }
        else {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

With this you shouldn't have problems with the scroll any more.

Answer (score 0):

you could just clear the tableView and reset the items all over again after updating the chekBox cell value:
table.getItems().clear();
table.setItems(getTbleInfo());